# The thinking behind regulatory alignment for goods

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Why is regulatory alignment in goods between the EU and the UK seen to be important?

Goods trade forms 20% of the UK economy and goods cross regulatory boundaries every day. Indeed most (and growing in share) UK exports are already sent outside the EU bloc, and almost half of UK imports are from outside the EU.

Furthermore maintaining regulatory alignment prevents a key element of Brexit, the onshoring of decision making for legislation (in this case for goods), it weakens the UK’s negotiating hand when seeking trade deals and it puts the regulatory environment for UK companies at the whim of people in Belgium.

On Northern Ireland, the volume of trade is low, it is a special case (essentially a war zone) and deserves special treatment - presumably a light touch monitoring solution would suffice. Even on “normal” highly trafficked borders, a tiny fraction of border crossings are inspected.

Given this, what is the thinking behind maintaining regulatory alignment for goods after leaving the EU?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain? This is an honest question.

Comment: Maybe so. My question still stands though.

Comment: As for your question regarding a *mutual recognition agreement*, that's impossible to answer without knowing the contents. As with any agreement, it depends on the contents if the EU and UK will agree to it. Without specifying what's in it, we cannot say or even comment on if it's feasible or not.

Comment: The EU has a population (without the UK) of nearly 500 million. In addition to that it has trade agreements with 70 other countries, which are  obliged to conform. Two-thirds of Britain's exports go to the EU +70. In a world where Britain represents 1% of the population, are you seriously suggesting it would be sensible to maintain our own separate standards, independently of anywhere else? As the EU is the world's largest trading entity, it makes perfect sense to adopt their rules as standard. How many civil servants would the UK  need to employ to set-up and maintain its own regulations?

Comment: I’m not “seriously suggesting” anything. I find the heat of the affected incredulity in your answer unhelpful. I am merely asking a question. In response to your comment, most standards are defined above the EU (eg vehicle standards at the UN ECE), so I don’t think anyone is suggesting we set up separate standards. My question is about standards acceptance. For example, I don’t see why it would take large numbers of civil servants to say “we accept Japanese and EU” phytosanitary standards, but I have little knowledge in this area, hence my question.

Comment: @Ben  Don't you ever wonder how Germany gets by perfectly well using EU standards? And they manage to sell six times (in dollar value) as much as we do, outside the EU.  Don't we want to ensure that when a country sells to us it has to meet "our" standards? And isn't the easiest thing simply to tell them that we accept goods that meet EU standards?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, since I do not agree to the reasons for putting it on hold. It doesn't seem to me to be in the least difficult to understand what is being asked. The question is contained in the very first sentence.  However I should have thought the answer was obvious, as I have pointed out in my comments.

Comment: Thank you. Germany is inside the EU. The UK will be outside the EU and will therefore be a different category of entity.

Comment: @Ben But in or out of the EU, it would seem vastly more convenient for the UK to accept EU standards, since they are well understood around the world. It would also avoid the horrendous cost of establishing a separate standards regime.

Comment: Accepting EU standards is fine. Regulatory alignment is totally different. You can accept EU standards and not be in regulatory alignment.

Answer (score 3):

> Given this, what is the thinking behind maintaining regulatory alignment for goods after leaving the EU?

To maintain the customs union.

The customs union basically says that regulations are enforced at the border between the European Union and the rest of the world.  If the United Kingdom is outside the customs union, then it is more difficult for the UK to export to the EU.  It is easier for UK businesses to compete by complying with the EU regulations and export freely than to have compliance rechecked at the EU border.  Since the EU is the most natural trading partner for the UK, most businesses would rather face universal enforcement of the regulations than only face regulations on EU exports.

The basic problem is that it is hard to only sometimes meet a regulation.  So businesses basically have to comply universally regardless.  But now they face additional hoops to trade with the EU as well as being forced to comply with the regulations.  Many businesses don't want that.

Many products that I buy have instructions in both English and French.  Why?  Because I live in an area of the United States that is close to Quebec.  So the same products I buy are also sold in Quebec.  Quebec requires French instructions because some residents cannot read English.  The sellers are complying with those regulations even for things sold purely in the US, where French is not required (far more people in the US speak Spanish as a first language than French).  This is so even though Quebec is small relative to the US and even the English speaking portion of Canada.

Similarly, it's easier for many UK businesses to comply with EU regulations all the time rather than only on exported products.  Because the EU is a large potential market.

Leaving the customs union makes imports from places other than the EU a bit easier.  But it makes exports to the EU a lot harder.  And of course the status quo is inside the customs union.  So the people who would benefit from easier trade outside the EU are less defined than the people who would be hurt from leaving.

Comment: The Customs Union ensures common tariffs are collected at the edges of the EU and these are sent to the EU, after applying a “collection charge”. I don’t see what this has to do with regulations.

Comment: @Ben the Customs Union also ensures only those products that satisfy regulations are imported

Comment: Not as far as I know. The Single Market harmonises goods and service regulations.

Comment: @Ben No the Single Market describes the *result*. Manufacturers within the EU have to follow EU regulations. Importers may only bring in goods that follow regulations. Once the goods exist within the EU, no further checking is needed.

Comment: I am confident that the Customs Union is simply a unified customs wall at the border of the EU (the CET) and the elimination of customs checks within the bloc. Goods regulations are covered by the Single Market. Do you have a link to disprove this?

Comment: @Ben You're correct, although customs is allowed to enforce the regulations on goods they have seized on other grounds (as in: not having documentation that shows you're compliant with regulations can be grounds to not release the goods). I've had this happen to something I had ordered from China, but I can't find an official statement. There's this though: https://www.webretailer.com/lean-commerce/eu-product-regulations/ .

Comment: @Ben if the EU would let the UK in the customs union without the UK taking over single market requirements (like regulations on goods) then other countries might file complaints with the EU for violating MFN in its FTA's with other countries, similar to [the argument put forward here (regarding financial services)](http://ukandeu.ac.uk/explainers/most-favoured-nation-principle-a-problem-for-uks-financial-services/).

Comment: This answer is clearly open to question. There are not _necessarily_ additional hoops to trading with the EU if regulatory alignment is not maintained, because the UK can continue to permit EU regulated goods onshore, so companies can continue manifacturing goods to EU standards for both EU and domestic sale if they wish. Instead I am asking about regulatiory alignment, which is different. Regulatory alignment _mandates_ that all UK companies meet all current _and future_ EU rules.

Comment: @Ben if you want to sell to the EU those goods must follow EU rules. If all your manufacturing follows these rules, it's sensible to be in the single market. If you want to sell to the EU and diverge from EU rules for some of your non-EU manufacturing, I think it's logical that there will have to be some check if the goods follow EU rules or not. That is normally done via customs checks. Customs checks are expensive, especially if you need a lot more than you used to (because most things came into the EU via Rotterdam, which is a deep-sea port just across the North Sea).

Answer (score 1):

The Customs Union doesn't require regulatory alignment. That is a function of the Single Market.

[How Custom Union Works](https://fullfact.org/europe/how-eu-works-what-customs-union/?gclid=CjwKCAjw9sreBRBAEiwARroYmz5lEFpwmUd6dk7GR3c0_1sBhXoGsfTaueV3qGCCCZntPV2dYg7LORoCUR4QAvD_BwE) [What is the Single Market](https://fullfact.org/europe/what-single-market/)

> The customs union is different to the single market which establishes common rules and regulations to promote the free movement of goods within the Union.

However the Question contends that regulatory alignment would prevent the UK negotiating it's own trade deals, but in fact it is membership of the Customs Union that block individual states from making their own trade deals as Tariff negotiation is the handled at the EU level.

> A common external tariff is the main distinctive feature of a customs union. It means that there is a common tariff border across the whole EU. It also means the ability to set those tariffs is transferred from member states to EU institutions.

The BBC Article [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-36083664) mentions that Turkey is a member of the Customs Union (although not for food or agriculture) without being a member of the Single Market, but doesn't go into detail on what that functionally means for Turkey as a country.

Logically being a member of the Customs Union without matching the regulatory requirements of the Single Market would suggest that you could move goods around without tariffs, but you couldn't sell them to anyone. As you can't sell things that fail to meet the Regulations.

Comment: “...but you couldn’t sell them to anyone” Most countries in the world do not have regulatory alignment (which is what my question is about) with the EU, and yet they ALL (barring sanctioned regimes) may sell into the EU Single Market. Their exports must meet EU rules, that is a given. But my question is about regulatory alignment, which is different.

Comment: But they're not selling from inside the Customs Union. So if for example Country X has lower regulatory standards for farm workers, the EU can limit imports from that country via tariffs or quotas into the Customs Union. That doesn't apply if the UK is inside the Customs Union to maintain a lack of border between NI/ROI.

Comment: I don’t follow your farm worker regulatory standards example. All countries that sell into the EU have different farm worker regulations to the EU. Importantly however, all goods sold into the EU from these countries meet EU standards (obv). The tariffs and quotas are not punitive for regulatory differences - they are to protect continental industry. How am I wrong? To restate: my contention is that membership of the CU simply means acting as tax collector for the EU. Regulations are orthogonal.

Comment: Despite being named separately I don't see how the Customs Union and the Single market can be sensibly separated, for an economy that wants to export to the EU. At what point would the EU confirm that a product meets regulatory standards if not at the Custom Border? Obviously Turkey does this somehow, but I haven't been able to find a layman explanation of what this practically means.

@Ben you also mention "weakens the UK's hand seeking trade deals" but even without regulatory alignment this is impossible within the CU, as the first quote/link I provided explains.

Comment: My understanding is that in practise regulatory checks are few and far between. Where such checks are performed is immaterial really. As I understand it customs checks are most frequently performed ahead of time using computer systems and trusted trader schemes.

Comment: @Ben this article about the various border crossings into the EU suggest that you're wrong. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-44054594 a 3 hour queue at the Turkey Bulgaria border, even with the odd CU arrangements doesn't sound very ahead of time to me.